# How do I use UPSERT in sqlite such that created_at time is preserved?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert, upsert

I'm trying to replace this INSERT statement with an UPSERT (now supported in sqlite)

```
 55     await db.query(
 56       "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO urls(url, title, excerpt, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
 57       [url, article.title, article.excerpt, new Date().toISOString(), new Date().toISOString()],
 58     );
```

I want to keep the original `created_at` timestamp and the other properties (aside from `url` which is the key) can be updated if the row already exists.

Bonus points if you can also add a `count = count + 1` column to the table for tracking views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a unique constraint for the column `url` then the syntax for [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) is:

```
INSERT INTO urls(url, title, excerpt, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT(url) DO UPDATE 
SET title = EXCLUDED.title, 
    excerpt = EXCLUDED.excerpt, 
    updated_at = EXCLUDED.updated_at;
```

If there is also a column `count`:

```
INSERT INTO urls(url, title, excerpt, created_at, updated_at, count) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1) 
ON CONFLICT(url) DO UPDATE 
SET title = EXCLUDED.title, 
    excerpt = EXCLUDED.excerpt, 
    updated_at = EXCLUDED.updated_at,
    count = count + 1;
```

or if you have defined `count` with a default value of 1 it can be omitted from the INSERT list:

```
INSERT INTO urls(url, title, excerpt, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
ON CONFLICT(url) DO UPDATE 
SET title = EXCLUDED.title, 
    excerpt = EXCLUDED.excerpt, 
    updated_at = EXCLUDED.updated_at,
    count = count + 1;
```

Comment: So the `EXCLUDED` refers to the original row? or is it updating with the new data?

Comment: @chovy EXCLUDED refers to the values in the VALUES list.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't appear to be necessary to add the `EXCLUDED` lines, as Sqlite didn't overwrite those lines on Update.